# equation positioning problem

Tags: equations, positioning

With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\rm \setlength{\parindent}{1cm} Estimatorul nonparametric pentru functia de distributie cumulative, $F(x)$, in punctul $x$ este raportul de puncte intermediare care sunt mai mici sau egale cu $x$.
\begin{equation}
\mathop{F}\limits^{\wedge } (x)=\frac{\# \{ x^{t} \le x\} }{N}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The equation is positioned at the center, but why? How can I align it to the left? And that (1) is automatically inserted?

Comment: In addition to prettygully's answer below, take a look at this question for more on the left-alignment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16840/86

Answer (score 4):

I would use `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}` -- this will place the equation a certain distance from the left margin; you can modify this by using something like `\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}`.

Answer (score 1):

The `equation` environment singles the start of a **numbered** and **displayed** mathematical environment.  It is the "numbered" part that is putting the `(1)` in your display, to remove that replace the `\begin{equation}` by `\[` and `\end{equation}` by `\]`.  Alternatively, you could use the `amsmath` package (`\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble) and use the `equation*` environment.

The "displayed" part is putting it on in the middle of the page.  To put it on the left depends slightly on what you mean by that.  A fairly crude method would be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\rm \setlength{\parindent}{1cm} Estimatorul nonparametric pentru functia de distributie cumulative, $F(x)$, in punctul $x$ este raportul de puncte intermediare care sunt mai mici sau egale cu $x$.

\(\displaystyle
\mathop{F}\limits^{\wedge } (x)=\frac{\# \{ x^{t} \le x\} }{N}
\)

\end{document}
```

[image: left-aligned equation]

(note the blank line between the paragraph and the mathematics).

I say "crude" because this doesn't do anything fancy with the spacing between the paragraphs before and after the mathematics and the mathematics.  There may well be a package which does exactly what you want ... if so, someone will no doubt stop by soon to share it!

Comment: Thanks.I don't know why the output .pdf is not generated. I have build the .tex document with Ctrl+F7 but i cannot see the pdf. Where it's generated, in which folder?

Comment: @qwerty: That sounds like something to do with the exact way in which you are producing your documents.  For that, the best reference is the help or user guide from whatever program it is.  I can't guess that from what you say - I've never used a program that uses `Ctrl+F7` as a shortcut.

Comment: It sounds like TeXnicCenter. It is most probably in the same folder as the source file which you compiled. But Andrew is right, we can only troubleshoot problems with LaTeX code.