# Left-alignment like Fleqn-option only for specific equations

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I want to left-align some equations. (Note: I want to align the equations themselves, not code  inside of the equations.)

I have the following example code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\text{I want to left-align this equation}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{and this one,}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{but not this one and others.}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this? The equations don't neccessarily have to be left-adjusted to the left text border, the more important goal is to align them to each other.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `flalign` and `flalign*` environments from [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\begin{equation*}
A = B
\end{equation*}
\begin{flalign*}
C = D &&
\end{flalign*}
\begin{flalign*}
E = F &&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Does not work with `\split` in equation environment

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already had tried `flalign`, but as I didn't know about the `&` at the end, it didn't work then...

Comment: Why is an extra & needed at the end?

Comment: @HackerBoss ---  Short answer: try deleting them and see what happens. Long answer: `flalign` is usually used for multiple columns of equations. It works by stretching the space between columns (see the [amsmath package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)). The first ampersand is usually an alignment point within the equations (but the OP didn't want this; hence it's at the end of the line). The second ampersand denotes the end of the column and generates the stretching space, aligning the first column of equations against the left margin.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to show an `eplain` version:

```
\input eplain
\leftdisplays
$$ \hbox{I want to left-align this equation} \eqno(1.1) $$
$$ \hbox{and this one,} $$
\centereddisplays
$$ \hbox{but not this one and others} \eqno(1.2) $$
\bye
```

because of the following remark from the [documentation](http://www.tug.org/docs/html/eplain/Displays.html#Displays):

> It is usually poor typography to have both centered and left-justified displays in a single publication, though.

Comment: I agree with you on that issue. I just want to use this in my appendix. But Thanks for this notice anyway :)